# How to start building a programming language in C?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, programming-languages

I really would love to go through the experience of building a compiler, lexer, and so on using C, however I havn't found a single resource on creating one. I've read the book about creating your own language using Ruby, but it just talks about how C is the best option, and won't tell you *where to go from there*.

Is their any nice resources for building a language using C? I don't care how long it is, I just want to know how to build one.

Comment: [The Dragon Book](http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Edition-ebook/dp/B004P5NQYI/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1).

Comment: Any number of introductory books on compilers would walk you through the process.  It may not be in C, but all the concepts translate into any language.

Comment: Also look at resources about lex and yacc (or flex and bison). C is the native language for these tools, and they will get the parsing part done. After that (at the latest), you'll need one of the books already mentioned.

Comment: I believe I've heard of The Dragon Book before, but I've long forgotten it. I'll be sure to check it out on Safari Books. :-)

Comment: @Chris if you use tools like lex and yacc you really miss out on the experience of writing the full compiler. I would suggest doing it from scratch the first time through.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen personally, I've always done it by hand (be it via recursive descent or nowadays combinator parsers). Mentioned them because they sort of force you into C ;-)

Comment: @Chris I had never heard of combinator parsing until you just mentioned it, read up on it for a few minutes and it sounds awesome! I am still using recursive descent

Comment: @HunterMcMillen yes, writing a parser in Haskell with Parsec or a similar library is pure joy compared to many other approaches (well, most of the time...)

Comment: If you want to write something in C, learn C. I have recently written a [simple C compiler in C](https://github.com/alexfru/SmallerC), which translates C code into assembly code that can then be assembled and linked into an executable. If you don't know C yet, you shouldn't probably try learning from that code. It's quite heavy and still needs clean up and more comments, and if you don't know assembly language, what's going on in the compiler is going to be a mystery for you. It's just a working example.

Comment: C is not the de-facto best choice, it's just what's available on (virtually) all platforms, unlike Ruby. Likewise, if your compiler produces C or assembly code, it will be easy to turn that into an executable because, again, C compilers and assemblers are available on all platforms.

Answer (score 3):

One of the nice things about compilers/interpreters is that it doesn't really matter what language they are written in. In the final stage they will just be an executable on someone's machine.

That being said while writing my compiler (something I am currently doing) I have used several books that have been extremely helpful:

1. [Compiler Construction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201403536) by Niklaus Wirth
2. [Compilers Principles, Techniques, and Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000LNTQTM) by Jeffrey Ullman, Alfred Aho, Ravi Sethi

The Wirth book will walk you through all the stages of creating a compiler for a language called Oberon-0. It also has the entire source code for his finished compiler, so you can play around with it on your own machine. The compiler itself was written in Pascal (something else that Wirth created).

The Dragon Book has really good information and examples in C! This may be what you are looking for, but as I said above, the language you write the compiler in isn't all that important.